# Can I have Varnish connect to a backend using a unix domain socket?

Tags: varnish, http-proxy

Tried this `VCL`, but it's not working:

```
backend nginx {
    .host = "/path/to/.s.NGINX";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet but it may get support http://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/PostTwoShoppingList#a31.UseUNIXsocketsforbackend

Comment: Ow, I see. Thanks anyway, I'll just use localhost:port until this gets implemented.